# File mm groove onto glass?

Tags: adhesive, glass

How can I go about filing a groove onto glass?

I want to adhere something slightly heavy onto glass. Since glass isn't the best in terms of gluing surface, I figured with a groove I can use gravity to help mount the object (along with glue).

Comment: Please consider to provide additional information regarding orientation of the glass, location of the groove, mounting bracket or device to be attached. Sketches are encouraged.

Comment: Scoring the glass will weaken it.  In fact when glass is cut the basically score to break the surface tension, then break it, it will fail easily along the score.

Comment: You should ask about a solution to your actual problem or challenge, not advice about your proposed solution which may not be appropriate to begin with.

Comment: How if instead scoring the glass surface, it is roughed using sand paper? Will this help for glue adhesion?

Comment: There are plenty of ways to bond to glass. Any abrasion will weaken it, with severity depending on the depth and quantity of the scoring.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to score the glass with a groove. Even the shallowest score mark in glass will create a line along which the glass will crack. In fact a glass cutter is nothing more than a very hard metal wheel attached to a tool handle that allows a score groove to be created across a sheet of glass.

Glass Cutter:

[image]

There are also specialty tools such as this glass bottle cutter that essentially is a mechanism to allow a score mark to be made around the outside of a bottle.

[image]